# ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createPortal') - Why?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error when trying to display the modal:

[image: This is the error i am getting]

My code is the following:
[image]

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The mistake is in import statment.

Replace

```
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom'
```

with

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```

**Reason :** As there is no  named export of ReactDOM from "react-dom", it is not imported and the reference will be undefined. So, you are getting the error. ***ReactDOM is default export.***

**UPDATE**

Replace

```
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom'
```

with

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
```

**Reason :** Now react does't support importing ReactDOM from react-dom instead it supports importing ReactDOM from react-dom/client

---

Answer (score 6):

For react v18 and above  the import statement does have client included

so replacing

```
import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom'
```

with

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

is advised
as per docs on [react portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the { } destructuring method for React-Dom, it will work.